# Many to Many with EF, FluentAPI and Identity

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I want to add a many-to-many-relationship to my database using EF 6.

I want to add a many to many between the `AppUser` and `Courses`. Here are my models:

#### AppUser

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WebApplication2.Models
{
    public class AppUser : IdentityUser<Guid>
    {
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstMidName { get; set; }
        public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
        public IList<AppUserCourse> AppUserCourses { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
    }
}
```

#### Course

```cs
namespace WebApplication2.Models
{
    public class Course
    {

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int CourseID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int Credits { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
        public IList<AppUserCourse> AppUserCourses { get; set; }
    }
}
```

#### AppUserCourse (Joined Table)

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication2.Models
{
    public class AppUserCourse
    {
        public Guid AppUserId { get; set; }
        public AppUser AppUser { get; set; }

        public int CourseId { get; set; }
        public Course Course { get; set; }
    }
}
```

#### `DataContext.cs`

```cs
using WebApplication2.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser, AppRole, Guid>
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AppUser> AppUsers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AppUserCourse> AppUserCourses { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().ToTable("Course");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Enrollment>().ToTable("Enrollment");

            modelBuilder.Entity<AppUserCourse>().HasKey(i => new { i.AppUserId, i.CourseId });
        }
    }
}
```

When I know do a migration and update my database, EF is creating my something strange in the `AppUserCourses-Table`:

[image: AppUserCourses-Table]

It creates my the `AppUserId` twice (`AppUserId` and `AppuserId1`): Former as `int` and latter as `uniqueidentifier`.

I would need it just once as **unique identifier**. When I now try to add a new `AppUserCourse`, I get the error message:

> Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int.

Comment: This is an interesting question. I've looked up if there are any quirks about the fluent api (because I know the attribute-approach in non-Core EF works), but [online resources seem to agree your approach should work](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-ef-core.aspx) (this is just one example of the many I've found). As far as I can see, your code is the same as theirs. I'm currently not in a position to shotgun debug any differences between your code and the code in my link, but I suspect there's some sneaky difference between the two.

Comment: Well, I think it is not working because EF is automatically generated the AppUserId for AppUserCourses as an int. Strangely, it is also creating an AppUserId (AppUserId1) with the correct Guid type (also see screenshot). But I don't know how to prevent this from happening.

Comment: As a debugging tip, maybe try defining the one-to-many relationships explicitly in your model builder. Your class seems to follow the conventions so it shouldn't be needed, but in the past I've learned that the EF's convention parser sometimes drops the ball when multiple configurations collide. Explicitly defining the one-to-manies excludes that possibility and can help EF in deciding how to generate the tables.

Answer (score -1):

On your AppUserCourse remove the entities, so it looks like the following, re-create your migrations too

```
 public class AppUserCourse
 {
    public Guid AppUserId { get; set; }
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
 }
```

That will create your many to many link

The following is an example I've set up

```
 public class Player
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public List<PlayerGroup> PlayerGroups { get; set; }
 }

 public class PlayerGroup
 {
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
 }

 public class Group
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }  
    public List<PlayerGroup> PlayerGroups { get; set; }
 }

 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<PlayerGroup>().HasKey(x => new {x.GroupId, x.PlayerId});
    }
```

Creates the following

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately. I can't do a migration because I get the error "AppUserCourse doesn't contain a definition of AppUser" and "AppUserCourse doesn't contain a definition of Course"

Comment: This wouldn't change the result.

Comment: Nav props are not the cause of the issue, the issue is how the composite keys are being generated (i.e. not reusing the FK columns, instead duplicating the columns). Did you test and confirm that this would solve it?

Comment: I've got an example where I'm doing what I've written in the comment abovee, not sure why it's marked down either! as it works. I use a List, not IList for the linking, although my example is using int's and not guids.